# PHP - Echo values from an array using a particular structure

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code:

```
$secondaryCatArray = array();
foreach($premiumCatArraySets as $key => $item){
  $secondaryCatArray[$item['secondary-category']][$key] = $item;
}
print_r($secondaryCatArray);
```

that gives the following output:

```
Array
(
    [Bride and Groom] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [primary-category] => Weddings
                    [secondary-category] => Bride and Groom
                    [tertiary-category] => Video
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [primary-category] => Weddings
                    [secondary-category] => Bride and Groom
                    [tertiary-category] => Make Up and Hair
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [primary-category] => Weddings
                    [secondary-category] => Bride and Groom
                    [tertiary-category] => Photography
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [primary-category] => Weddings
                    [secondary-category] => Bride and Groom
                    [tertiary-category] => Wedding Dresses
                )

            [13] => Array
                (
                    [primary-category] => Weddings
                    [secondary-category] => Bride and Groom
                    [tertiary-category] => Organisers
                )

        )
```

I would like the output from the above foreach loop to be displayed as follow:

```
<h1>Weddings</h1>
<h2>Bride and Groom</h2>
<h3>Video</h3>
<h3>Make Up and Hair</h3>
<h3>Photography</h3>
```

I know this may be very simple, but I'm not sure how to go around it.

Comment: html code+foreach loop

Comment: @SML That's what I'm trying to do ;-) but I want them sorted

Comment: *hmm*, instead of `$secondaryCatArray[$item['secondary-category']][$key] = $item;`, you should do this: `$secondaryCatArray[$item['primary-category']][$item['secondary-category']][] = $item['tertiary-category'];`. It will give you a better array structure to work with.

Comment: Still not working.... My purpose is to take the array and group it under various headings.

Comment: do you want to group them by primary and secondary category then echo all the value of the tertiary category? are you data structure set or you are free to design it?

Comment: @SML Yes, please. That is what I want to achieve.... It would be like a list subdivided into the 1st heading (in this case only one), 2nd subheading(containing various 3 level headings), then then 3rd subheading which subdivides the 2nd level heading - As in my example in my question

Comment: @user6043723 added the code, should fit all of your criteria, test it out and let me know if there is any problem

Comment: @user6043723 you should note that the answer you accepted would show <h1></h1><h1></h1><h2></h2><h2></h2><h3></h3><h3></h3><h3></h3><h3></h3><h3></h3> instead of <h1></h1><h2></h2><h3></h3><h1></h1><h2></h2><h3></h3> if you have two primary and two secondary category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each arrays in "Bride and Groom" array, loop over this arrays and fill an array with the h* tag as array key who correspond with your desired category.

After that you need to loop over your new array and for each h* key you build your output :

```
        $category = array(
            'h1' => array(),
            'h2' => array(),
            'h3' => array()
        );
        $output = '';
        foreach ($secondaryCatArray as $brideAndGroom){
            foreach ($brideAndGroom as $array){
                foreach ($array as $categoryType => $value){
                    if($categoryType == 'primary-category' && !in_array($value, $category['h1'])){
                        $category['h1'][] = $value;
                    }
                    if($categoryType == 'secondary-category' && !in_array($value, $category['h2'])){
                        $category['h2'][] = $value;
                    }
                    if($categoryType == 'tertiary-category' && !in_array($value, $category['h3'])){
                        $category['h3'][] = $value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach ($category as $h => $array){
            foreach ($array as $value){
                $output .= '<'.$h.'>'.$value.'</'.$h.'>';
            }
        }

        print_r($output);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @Rizier123 I added code explanation, I hope it's more clear

Comment: @shlowmo, I got an  error of Undefined index with the code?

Comment: @SML at which line ?

Comment: @shlowo I put your code starting on line 17 and this is the errors I got <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: h1 in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>22</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>22</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: h3 in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>28</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>28</b><br />

Comment: just want to clarify your code only intends to work with one primary and one secondary category, is that right?

Comment: @SML if you have several primary an secondary category the output of my code will be :
h1
h1
h2
h2
h3
h3
h3

Comment: Gotcha. Sorry I am not trying to be a pain, but please check your code again, as there are new errors<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: category in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>20</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>20</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: h2 in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>23</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>23</b><br />
<br />

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one primary and one secondary category, you can simply hard-code the `<h1>` and `<h2>` in.

```
    echo"<h1>Weddings<\h1>";
    echo"<h2>Bride and Groom<\h2>";
    foreach($arr['Bride and Groom'] as $item){
         foreach($item as $key => $value){
              if ($key=='tertiary-category'){
                    echo "<h3>".$value."</h3>";
              }           
        }
    }
```

If you have multiple primary and secondary categories, you can use a sort by column function to sort your array before putting it in the foreach loop, this way you have control over the display order using simple if/else. See inline code comments for more details.

```
  $primaryCat="";
  $secondaryCat="";

//sort $array by tertiary, secondary then primary category
    array_sort_by_column($arr['Bride and Groom'], 'tertiary-category');
    array_sort_by_column($arr['Bride and Groom'], 'secondary-category');
    array_sort_by_column($arr['Bride and Groom'], 'primary-category');

    foreach($arr['Bride and Groom'] as $key => $item){
         foreach($item as $key => $value){
//new primary category, assign name of category to $primaryCat
              if ($key=='primary-category' && $primaryCat!=$value){
                        $primaryCat=$value;
                        unset($secondaryCat);
              }
//new secondary category, assign name of category to $secondaryCat
//echo name of category 1 and 2 with h1 and h2 tag, since the array has already been sorted alphabetically by column, h1 h2 tag will only appear once before all the name of tertiary category under those two parent categories are displayed.
              else if ($key=='secondary-category' && $secondaryCat!=$value){ 
                        $secondaryCat =$value;
                        echo "<h1>".$primaryCat."</h1>";
                        echo "<h2>".$secondaryCat."</h2>";
              }
              else if ($key=='tertiary-category'){
                    echo "<h3>".$value."</h3>";
              }                
        }
    }
//sort by column function    
    function array_sort_by_column(&$arr, $col, $dir = SORT_ASC) {
        $sort_col = array();
        foreach ($arr as $key=> $row) {
            $sort_col[$key] = $row[$col];
        }        
        array_multisort($sort_col, $dir, $arr);
    }
```

Sample data

```
Array
(
    [Bride and Groom] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [primary-category] => Weddings
                    [secondary-category] => Bride and Groom
                    [tertiary-category] => Video
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [primary-category] => Weddings
                    [secondary-category] => Bride and Groom
                    [tertiary-category] => Make up and Hair
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [primary-category] => Weddings
                    [secondary-category] => Bride and Groom
                    [tertiary-category] => Something else
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [primary-category] => Weddings
                    [secondary-category] => Add on
                    [tertiary-category] => Aerial Photo
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [primary-category] => Weddings
                    [secondary-category] => Add on
                    [tertiary-category] => Limo
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [primary-category] => Weddings
                    [secondary-category] => Add on
                    [tertiary-category] => Something else
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [primary-category] => Bridal
                    [secondary-category] => Bachelorette Party
                    [tertiary-category] => Video
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [primary-category] => Bridal
                    [secondary-category] => Bachelorette Party
                    [tertiary-category] => Make up and Hair
                )

        )

)
```

Click on the Snippet for Output of sample data

```html
<h1>Bridal</h1><h2>Bachelorette Party</h2><h3>Make up and Hair</h3><h3>Video</h3><h1>Weddings</h1><h2>Add on</h2><h3>Aerial Photo</h3><h3>Limo</h3><h3>Something else</h3><h1>Weddings</h1><h2>Bride and Groom</h2><h3>Make up and Hair</h3><h3>Something else</h3><h3>Video</h3>
```